# Setting defaults for Rendered form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails app set up with a scaffold set up for 'products'. I also created a new foo controller and view. I have a partial form from my products model in my foo index. In my foo controller I have various variables defined. How can I pass these variables in as defaults into the products form that is being rendered as a partial into my foo index?

My Form:

```
<%= form_for @product, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">Feed ID
    <%= params[:feed_id] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag('passed_feed_id', params[:feed_id]) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :uploadedimage %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :uploadedimage %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_names %>
    <%= f.text_field :category_names, :size => 65 %>
    <%= f.label :categories %>
    <%= f.text_field :categories %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <span><%= f.check_box :published %> <%= f.label :published %> </span>
  </div> 

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :url %>
    <%= f.text_field :url %>

    <%= f.label :canonical_url %>
    <%= f.text_field :canonical_url %>

    <%= f.label :image_url %>
    <%= f.text_field :image_url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :long_descr %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :long_descr %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :mp_seller_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :mp_seller_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :curr_item_price %>
    <%= f.text_field :curr_item_price %>
    <%= f.label :base_item_price %>
    <%= f.text_field :base_item_price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :id_str %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :id_str %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :id %>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

From your index view, you need to render to partial with hash of controller instance variables. Refer [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but you might want to try passing local variables to your partial.

For example

```
<%= render :partial => "foo/form", :locals => { :a => 3, :b => "bar", :c => @baz } %>
```

Then from within your partial you can make use of `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Checkout the passing local variables section of the rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: This is the how its rendered in my view: <%= render :partial => 'products/form', :locals => { :title => @title }  %> and ":title" is whats called in the form and "@title" is a variable declared in the controller of the view im rendering the partial, however when i submit the product the parameters are blank:Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"JDNJLNfjlnejddfnjwenr3njnrefjnfjl=",
 "passed_feed_id"=>"832",
 "product"=>{"title"=>"",

Comment: Addeed controller code above, this is all I have in my partial <%= render :partial => 'products/form', :locals => { :title => @title }  %>

Comment: Sorry what is in the the file `apps/views/products/_form.html.erb` ?

Comment: The form_for tag is inferring the :title from your @product variable. If you want to change the label then do something like `<%= f.label :title, "New Title" %>`